# How to configure Ctrl+Alt+F1 to F6 to use with putty instances in Windows?

Tags: putty, tty, shortcut

Is it possible to set up putty (or [a](http://haanstra.eu/putty/) fork), have multiple terminals/logins open while fullscreen, but each one with a single dedicated shortcut for switching to it?

Just like `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1` to F6 switches tty terminals in many Linux systems. (To be honest I intend to attach these shortcuts to my putty sessions/terminals/logins.)

Comment: Start a gnu screen session.  Do some key-mapping magic that re-maps the f-keys to switch to the correct screen window?

Answer (score 1):

There is a third party app called quickputty (available on the official putty page) that will display a menu for easily switching between the putty xterms you have running.